ERROR: Connecting to database failed: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: role "mapper" does not exist
I was trying to set up a geospatial database by following this tutorial https://www.volkerschatz.com/net/osm/offlineosm.html so i installed posgresql and created a role mapper using createuser mapper , created the gis database using createdb -E UTF8 -O mapper gis and then executed these 3 lines to set up the database
psql -d gis -f /usr/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/postgis.sql
psql -d gis -c "ALTER TABLE spatial_ref_sys OWNER TO mapper;"
psql -d gis -U mapper -f /usr/share/postgresql/contrib/postgis-2.1/spatial_ref_sys.sql

. Now the thing is when i try to exec osm2psql command osm2pgsql -s -d gis -C 2000 --number-processes 3 -U mapper ./data/cameroon-latest.osm.bz2, i get this error
ERROR: Connecting to database failed: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "mapper" does not exist

which i don't understand since i created the role mapper.
I checked with the \du command to see if the role mapper was there
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 mapper    |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}

and it was. I even tried to recreate it using CREATE ROLE mapper LOGIN; and CREATE ROLE "mapper" LOGIN; but i got the error saying that the role already exist. So i don't really understand what might be the problem there. I am open to any form of help or suggestion. Thank you.

Are you using docker or virtualization?

From: https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html
Option                | Description
----------------------------------------
-d, --database=DB     | Database name or PostgreSQL conninfo string.
-U, --user=USERNAME   | Database user.
-W, --password        | Force password prompt.
-H, --host=HOST       | Database server hostname or unix domain socket location.
-P, --port=PORT       | Database server port.
--schema=SCHEMA       | Version >= 1.9.0 Default for various schema settings throughout osm2pgsql (default: public). The schema must exist in the database and be writable by the database user.

You have to specify -H with your host ip. If it is localhost you can use:
osm2pgsql -U 127.0.0.1 -s -d gis -C 2000 --number-processes 3 -U mapper ./data/cameroon-latest.osm.bz2

Also consider to use -P if you have multiple instances of Postgres.
